# Why is my service inside NgOnInit keeps getting called by the application on button click?

Tags: angular, observable

Right now, I have an Angular components that need to get number values and name of CSS classes from a service and place it properly in the component view. The data is displayed properly, and it looks something like this:

[image: rating1]

But if click on the next page button in the screen, and return the page back, there appears another row of the button, and if i moved page and return again, it renders another row of button

[image: rating2]

I tried changing the lifecycle based on the documentation(https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) from OnInit to other things but it still showed the same thing.

```
  //other code
  //The loop to display the button in view
  <div class="buttonForSlider">
    <div *ngFor="let button of listOfButtons">
      <div class="{{button.initialDivClass}}">
          <span class='btn ratingButton {{button.typeOfButtonClass}} font-weight-bold' [ngClass]="{clickedButtonSlider: button.isClicked}" (click) = "changeSliderValue(button.value)">{{button.value}}</span><div class="{{button.seperatorClass}}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  //other code
```

The typescript of the component:

```
  emojiPath = "";
  minSlider = 0;
  maxSlider = 10;
  tickInterval: number = 0;
  listOfButtons: QuestionSlider[] = [];
  isCalled: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getNumberOfButtons();
  }

  getNumberOfButtons(){
  this.questionSliderService.getButtonForSlider(this.minSlider, this.maxSlider)
  .subscribe(listOfButtons =>
    {
      this.listOfButtons = listOfButtons;
    }
  )
  //other code
```

The service file:

```
  export class QuestionSliderService {
  listOfButtons: QuestionSlider[] = []
  i: number = 0;
  getButtonForSlider(minValue: number, maxValue: number){
  for(this.i = minValue; this.i <= maxValue; this.i++){
  if(this.i == minValue){
    this.listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: 'buttonPositioning',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnHead',
      seperatorClass: 'seperator',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }

  else if(this.i == maxValue){
    this.listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: '',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnTail',
      seperatorClass: '',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }

  else{
    this.listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: 'buttonPositioning',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnMiddle',
      seperatorClass: 'seperator',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }
}
return of(this.listOfButtons);
}
}
```

I want the page to only display the row of buttons once, not repeated again and again everytime I move to the next page. Can you guys help me with this problem? I think I made the wrong use of lifecycle, but I'm not too sure since I've tried changing it to the ones inside the documentation but it produces the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your `QuestionSliderService` still exists after you leave your page.
Therefore the variable `listOfButtons` in your service is still filled with the values of the previous execution of the method `getButtonForSlider`.

A quick solution would be to either return the values directly instead of saving them in a class variable

```
  export class QuestionSliderService {
  i: number = 0;
  getButtonForSlider(minValue: number, maxValue: number){
  listOfButtons: QuestionSlider[] = []
  for(this.i = minValue; this.i <= maxValue; this.i++){
  if(this.i == minValue){
    listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: 'buttonPositioning',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnHead',
      seperatorClass: 'seperator',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }

  else if(this.i == maxValue){
    listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: '',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnTail',
      seperatorClass: '',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }

  else{
    listOfButtons.push({
      value: this.i,
      initialDivClass: 'buttonPositioning',
      typeOfButtonClass: 'btnMiddle',
      seperatorClass: 'seperator',
      isClicked: false
    });
  }
}
return of(listOfButtons);
}
}
```

or to implement a clearButtons() method that you call first in your ngOnInit

```
  // in your component
  ngOnInit() {
     this.questionSliderService.clearButtons();
     this.getNumberOfButtons();
  }

  // in your service
  clearButtons() {
     this.listOfButtons = []
  }
```